# Unable to receive Push notifications to Notifications Tray on Appcelerator Android

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, appcelerator-mobile

I have been trying to get Push notifications working for an android application. When the app is focussed, the push is received just fine. However, when the application is in the background, i see an error in the log.

My code is -

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        console.log('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
        token = e.deviceToken;
        that.token=token;
    },
    error: function deviceTokenError(e) {
        console.log('Token Error: ' + e.error);
    }
});

CloudPush.debug                 = true;
CloudPush.focusAppOnPush        = false;
CloudPush.enabled               = true;
// CloudPush.showAppOnTrayClick = false;
CloudPush.showTrayNotification  = true;
// CloudPush.singleCallback     =  true;

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt){
    alert('A push notification was received!');
    console.log('A push notification was received!' + JSON.stringify(evt));
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function(evt){
    alert('A push notification was received - onLaunched');
    console.log('A push notification was received!' + JSON.stringify(evt));
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function(evt){
    alert('A push notification was received - onFocused');
    console.log('A push notification was received!' + JSON.stringify(evt));
});
```

and the error i am receiving is -

```
07-18 14:19:44.853: E/TiApplication(25319): (main) [9,46101] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver ti.cloudpush.GCMReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException; Titanium 3.2.3,2014/04/22 10:17,b958a70 
07-18 14:19:44.853: E/TiApplication(25319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver ti.cloudpush.GCMReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any thoughts on how i could work this out is highly appreciated.

Im using Titanium SDK - 3.2.3 GA.

Comment: Did you just set up your environment and are using the emulator? I'm having the same issue but not seeing any solutions on google :( . I followed this http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.CloudPush and have the same issue. I appear to be having the same issue.

Comment: hey @Ed_ No, i was not using an emulator. After hours of breaking my head, I eventually stumbled onto this resource - iamyellow.net/post/40100981563/gcm-appcelerator-titanium-module and it sort of worked as i wanted it to. Easy to setup too. I would suggest you to try it. Let me know it goes.

Comment: I have created a ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4476 . Its got to be a bug. I can't see the solution being us a different 3rd party module for something as core as push notifications.

Comment: The TC-4476 bug has been updated with a comment, did that fix it?

Comment: Hi @phil. Not really. For some reason they have put up in the mentioned git, the same code that is already available in the Appcelerator Documentation.

Comment: oh well. It's probably the first step for them in resolving any bug.